# CarrierWave URL for uploading image using with cloudinary

Tags: json, api, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4

I were using cloudinary for image uploading, but now i integrate this process with CarrierWave, all work goes perfact and now i want to use url with CarrierWave not with cloudinary like this:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/doejo/image/upload/v1401968816/kqg1xxwaehucszvngk4f.jpg
```

here is my ImageSerializer code

```
class ProductImageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :small, :medium, :large

  def small
    url(width: 116, height: 116, crop: "fill")
  end

  def medium
    url(width: 640, height: 400, crop: "fill")
  end

  def large
    url(width: 1000, crop: "fill")
  end

  private

  def url(options={})
    options[:format] = "png"
    options[:secure] = true

    Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(object.token, options)
  end
end
```

how can i generate carrierwave url so that i can see image url with CarrierWave not with cloudinary , please guide.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by CarrierWave url? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I were using cloudinary for image uploading and for api there is image attribute in my Serializer, which gives a image URl, and this is done by using cloudinary Utils, and now i integrated this process with careerwave and wish not to use this method anymore

Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(object.token, options)

looking for way to output image url which use or belongs to  carrierwave helpers or something like....

Comment: i found a simple solution to replace this code
---->>> Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(object.token, options)
with
---->>> object.image_url(options)
please update if there is more suitable solution thanks

Comment: Got it. In this case, object.image_url(options) is the way to go. You can also define version in your CarrierWave Uploader and use object.image.small.url

Comment: cool, works fine. you can post it as answer. thank you @Tal

Answer (score 1):

You can define small/medium/large as versions in your CarrierWave Uploader file and then use object.image.small.url etc.